# Weird spacing and border issue in html email sent to outlook 2010

Tags: outlook, html-email, outlook-2010

I am sending simple html mail that has one simple table.
The mail appears just fine in all web browsers but outlook 2010 seems odd.
How to fix this? I tried several variations, but result is same.

See the outlook screenshot here:

Outlook 2010:

[image]

Firefox:

[image]
Here is the html source:

```
<table style="width:500px;font:9pt Arial;background-color:#f6f6f6;" cellspacing="12px">
        <tr>
          <td style="border-bottom:1px solid #e6e6e6;">
            <span style="font-size:18px;color:#0033cc;">
              <b>
                <a href="url" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none">Birthday Invitation</a>
              </b>
            </span>
            <br />
            <div style="clear:both;color:#666;overflow:hidden;padding:5px 0 7px;">
              Note: Testing
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="border-bottom:1px solid #e6e6e6;padding-bottom:13px;">
            <br />
            <br />
            <b>HOST</b>
            <br />
            <span style="color:red">Host</span>            
          </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Padding and margin are not supported in Outlook 07 or 10. This is due to the great decision to use the word rendering engine rather than a browser rendering engine.

You need to use spacer gifs instead to get the layout you desire.

Wherever you have margin or padding replace with a suitable sized spacer image.

Answer (score 0):

Very late to the party, but you need to remove the `cellspacing="12px"`, and use it only to zero out.

Table tag should look like this: `<table width="500" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">`

Add padding to the `<td>`'s instead.

You should also declare your font in the `<td>`'s and not use the shorthand. `bgcolor="#f6f6f6"` is fully supported, while the css version isn't.